# Picker, setting startup / default row?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Does anyone know a way that I can set my picker to default / startup with row values that are not right at the start of my datasource? If possible I would like the picker to start with a middle value so I don't get the blank white area at the top.

[image]

## EDIT_001

Added the following lines to viewDidLoad, which seems to be the best place to call these as the UI is being built.

```
[doublePicker selectRow:2 inComponent:kCoffeeIndex animated:NO];
[doublePicker selectRow:2 inComponent:kCakeIndex animated:NO];
```

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -selectRow:inComponent:animated: for that.

Comment: I see, so where would that go as I only want it to fire when the UI is first displayed. Does it go in one of the datasource methods?